# Default Tab is adding twice in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://jsfiddle.net/t5q37nbe/2/

First of all, I have created a tab section using AntDesign library. The problem that I have is Tab-1 is default Tab. As soon as the code runs, it automatically opens with the Tab-1. On clicking the ADD Tab-1 button, another tab-1 gets popped. I don't want that to happen. On clicking Tab-1 it shouldn't open a new tab again.

Here I have set '1' for focusing and openingpane in order to be default,

```
 this.state = {
  focusingPaneKey: '1',
  openingPaneKeys: [1],
}
```

Can any one help me in solving this glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React code :**

```js
const { Tabs, Button } = antd
const { TabPane } = Tabs

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      focusingPaneKey: '1',
      openingPaneKeys: ['1'],
    }
  }

  openPane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (!state.openingPaneKeys.includes(paneKey)) {
        state.openingPaneKeys = [...state.openingPaneKeys, paneKey]
      }

      state.focusingPaneKey = paneKey
      return state
    })
  }

  closePane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (paneKey === state.focusingPaneKey) {
        const paneKeyIndex = state.openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
        state.focusingPaneKey = state.openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1]
      }

      state.openingPaneKeys = state.openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey)

      return state
    })
  }

  handleTabsEdit = (key, action) => {
    if (action === 'remove') {
      this.closePane(key)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { panes } = this.props
    const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
            <Button key={key} onClick={() => this.openPane(key)}>
              ADD Tab-{key}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.openPane}
          activeKey={this.state.focusingPaneKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.handleTabsEdit}
        >
          {this.state.openingPaneKeys
            .map((key) => panes[key])
            .map((pane) => (
              <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                {pane.content}
              </TabPane>
            ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const panes = {
  1: { key: '1', title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
  2: { key: '2', title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
  3: { key: '3', title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
}

ReactDOM.render(<App panes={panes} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

The issue is in types of openingPaneKeys array. You need to make the below change in your code.

```
    this.state = {
      focusingPaneKey: '1',
      openingPaneKeys: ['1'],
    }
  }
```

When you are checking `!state.openingPaneKeys.includes(paneKey)`, here **paneKey** is a string(i.e "1") but **state.openingPaneKeys** had **[1]** (a number). As 1 is not same "1" it returned false in your case.

Full working code at fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1gpLc9tn/

Comment: Instead of using JSFiddle you can [include the working React code here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) by using the `[<>]` snippet feature in the edit menu.

Comment: sure. updated :)

Comment: @AnkitSaxena I have doubt, how can I remove close button for default tab which is Tab-1, so that all the tabs will have closing option except Tab-1.

Comment: @UserD you can add an if condition like this - ``` if (paneKey > 1) `` in your ```closePane``` function . 

After that change your ```closePane``` will look something like this:

```closePane = (paneKey) => {
  if (paneKey > 1) {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
//rest of the code
```

Comment: @AnkitSaxena Can you please edit in the fiddle that you have shared.

Comment: @UserD, I have updated the fiddle link. please check

Comment: @AnkitSaxena How can That 'x' also be removed?

Comment: @UserD for removing the 'x' icon you need to look into the library that you're using for showing tabs. There should be some prop or configuration to change the icon properties.

Comment: @AnkitSaxena Hi Ankit, I just want your help....                                                                                    The problem here is, a tab is already opened, on clicking the same tab, paneCount is adding. I don't want paneCount to be added on clicking the same tab, once the tab is already opened.